# Logging in as root with sudo shows strange prompt

Tags: sudo, ps1

When I log in as root,

```
luvpreet@DHARI-Inspiron-3542:/$ sudo su
```

I am getting something like this:

```
\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$
```

What does this mean and why am I seeing it?

EDIT - 
Here are some more helpful things asked for in comments,

```
luvpreet@DHARI-Inspiron-3542:/$ sudo su -
DHARI-Inspiron-3542#  
DHARI-Inspiron-3542# exit
luvpreet@DHARI-Inspiron-3542:/$ sudo -i
\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ 
\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ exit
luvpreet@DHARI-Inspiron-3542:/$ echo $0
/bin/bash
```

EDIT 2 - refered to comments made

```
luvpreet@DHARI-Inspiron-3542:/$ ls -1 /root/.[a-zA-Z0-9]*
ls: cannot access '/root/.*': Permission denied
luvpreet@DHARI-Inspiron-3542:/$ sudo su -
DHARI-Inspiron-3542# ls -1d /root/.[a-zA-Z0-9]*
/root/.bash_history
/root/.bashrc
/root/.bashrc.bk
/root/.profile
/root/.profile.bk
/root/.viminfo
/root/.zcompdump
```

EDIT 3 -

```
luvpreet@DHARI-Inspiron-3542:/etc/ansible$ sudo find /root /etc/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec grep -n PS1 {} +
/root/.zcompdump:1201:'-value-,PS1,-default-' '_ps1234'
/root/.zcompdump:1207:'-value-,RPS1,-default-' '_ps1234'
/root/.bashrc:60:    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
/root/.bashrc:62:    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
/root/.bashrc:69:    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
/root/.bashrc.bk:9:[ -z "$PS1" ] && return
/root/.bashrc.bk:56:    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
/root/.bashrc.bk:58:    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
/root/.bashrc.bk:65:    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
/etc/profile:7:if [ "$PS1" ]; then
/etc/profile:9:    # The file bash.bashrc already sets the default PS1.
/etc/profile:10:    # PS1='\h:\w\$ '
/etc/profile:16:      PS1='# '
/etc/profile:18:      PS1='$ '
/etc/bash.bashrc:7:[ -z "$PS1" ] && return
/etc/bash.bashrc:19:PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
```

Comment: what if you run `sudo su -` or `sudo -i` ? what is your shell and terminal? IT's `$PS` variable (Prompt);

Comment: Looks like a possible shell syntax incompatibility - what shell are you using as default? You can find this out by running `echo $0`

Comment: updated the question

Comment: Ravexina means PS1 (`echo $PS1` shows it). It's not being interpreted

Comment: yeah, `echo $PS1` gives `\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$`

Comment: Recently, all I did was added jenkins user in `/etc/sudoers` file.

Comment: Can you show us what you entered with `sudo cat /etc/sudoers`? Might not be of consequence, but worth looking at just to eliminate.

Comment: just these lines, 
`jenkins ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`
`luvpreet ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`

Comment: Give it a shot ... `sudo su -` then: `cd /root` after that: `mv .bashrc{,.bk}` and `mv .profile{,.bk}`. finally: `cp /etc/skel/{.bashrc,.profile} .` use `exit` to get out of root shell then try `sudo su` and always use `sudo -i` or `sudo su -` to switch into root shell ;) let me know if it worked.

Comment: No @Ravexina it didn't work.

Comment: What is the output of `ls -1 /root/.[a-zA-Z0-9]*`?

Comment: updated the question !

Comment: Can you add the output of `sudo find /root /etc/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec grep -n PS1 {} +` to your question?

Comment: added, I think this will help you

Comment: Everything seems fine, use `sudo su` to switch into root then run `export PS1="\u@\h-\W:`, what happens ?

Comment: \[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ export PS1="\u@\h-\W":

This changes to ,

`\u@\h-\W:`